# ajaxで取得したhtmlのhead内を操作したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery(3.3.1)のajaxで得たhtmlデータのhead内に対して操作をしたいです。
以下のようにscriptタグ内に書かれたjsを表示しようとしましたが、コンソールに何も表示されません。何が原因なのでしょうか？
（もちろんですがドメインは一緒で他のディレクトリのページです）

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: targetUrl,
    timeout: 1000,
    datatype: "html"
}).then(function(data){
    $(data).find('head').find('script').each(function(index, el) {
        console.log(el.text());
    });
},function(){
    //略
});
```

色々調べたのですが分からなかったので、質問させて頂きました。
ご回答の程、よろしくお願い致します。

質問しておいてアレですが、

```
$(data).filter('script').text();
```

で script 内のjsが取得できました。これでやりたいことができそうです。
ご回答頂いた皆様、ありがとうございました。

Comment: jQueryのバージョン情報を追記いただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: バージョンは3.3.1です。(Google CDN)

Comment: dataは文字列かと思いますが、dataの最初の文字列は何からはじまりますか？<html>などのタグ?それとも違う文字列？

Comment: console.log(data) では <!DOCTYPE html> から全て表示され、console.log(typeof data) では string と表示されています。

Comment: HTMLパースされてない可能性がありますかね？明示的にパースするとどうなりますか？https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: console.log(jQuery.parseHTML(data)); でよく分からない配列が表示されました。中身はタグやら #text"" となっていました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すでに自己解決しているようですが、一応

`$.ajax` で取得したウェブページのデータ(文字列)を扱う場合は [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) を利用する手段もあります。これを `$` でラップすれば jQuery API 群が使えるようになります。

```
$.ajax({
    /* 中略 */
}).then(function(data) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html"); //=> HTMLDocument
    $(doc).find('head > script').each(function(index, el) {
        console.log(el.text());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery関数](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)では次のように説明されています。

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

`.innerHTML`を使用して解析を行うため、ブラウザーによっては`<html>`、`<title>`、`<head>`などのタグが省略されることがあるそうです。ですので、今回の用途には使えなさそうです。